# Visualizing code diffs on posts (not edits)

Tags: feature-request, diff

This question is **not** about the `diff` tool used to validate post edits.

In many posts, the first person asks a question and provides some code, the reply contains some code as well. In some cases, it is hard for a user to see the difference at first sight.

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268223/invalid-uri-in-request-trying-to-proxy-iframe-content-for-local-debugging) (only used as an example, no insult intended)

A possible additional feature could offer to show the difference between two chunks of code (as is done for reviewing post-edits).

Algorithms could detect the similarity between two files (for instance counting the number of lines that differ or the number of characters) automatically, or possibly a user could enable some `diff` feature manually. The tool could for instance highlight added lines in green, removed lines in red and modified lined in yellow.

Comment: Too complex in my opinion. The answer author is expected to explain the difference anyway. Wall of code answer without any explanation is low quality anyway, and should be edited if possible, or downvoted even if the code itself is not wrong.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I agree a user should explain his/her answer. But a quick `diff` can improve the answer and speed up people understanding that answer (if for instance a single line was missing), it's easy to see this on a diff.

Comment: If this required the reader to click on something to see the diff, I think it's a poor solution. I will often put a comment in the code next to the added/modified line, if the explanation doesn't make it obvious; perhaps there should be a markdown feature that recognizes specially formatted comments so they get highlighted (rather than dimmed like most comments). However, deletions don't admit to this solution as well.